# Application updates fail

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, error, 2019

After applying updates to SharePoint, it fails.

Most databases have been updated, but when checking `stsadm.exe -o localupgradestatus`

1. Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebSite
   Status: Unable to update;
2. Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb
   status: update required;

The error is logged:

> ERROR Exception: The system cannot find the path specified. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
>   03/02/2019 11: 01: 15.06 PSCONFIG (0x5820) 0x5E38 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPUpgradeSession an58c;
>   ERROR in System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind (Boolean throwIfFail) in System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind () in System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject () in System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList () in System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection. .ctor (DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName) in System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item (String propertyName) in Microsoft. SharePoint.Upgrade.SPSequence.get_CanUpgrade () in Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.CanUpgrade (Object o) 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000;

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this issue may be caused by deleted web applications. Check if you have deleted any web applications ever and these web application also are hanging on IIS. If yes, you can delete them.

Then re-run SharePoint Products Configuration Wizards.
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebSite type object needs upgrade](http://sharepointviews.com/microsoft-sharepoint-administration-spiiswebsite-type-object-needs-upgrade/)

Comment: Yes, a test web application was created, but then deleted. How to remove leftovers from this web application? There is nothing in iis.